# FileNameExtensionFilter alternative?

Tags: java, file, file-extension

I am working on an app that has to be able to run on Java 5 and requires some file name extension filtering. I know there is the FileNameExtensionFilter  that was introduced in Java 6, but that won't work for me since I need something that works in Java 5. Is there are alternative method or class that could make this possible?

Comment: What about [`FilenameFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FilenameFilter.html)?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza this is not a Swing component

Comment: @fge this interface interacts with `java.io.File`. It is not directly related with swing components. Have you used it in the past to begin with? If not, have you at least read its javadoc (since I added the link to it)?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza no, but that is not the problem here. It seems OP wants some javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter.

Comment: @fge by reading JavaDoc and example of [`FileNameExtensionFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileNameExtensionFilter.html), is just an extension of [`FileFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileFilter.html) (javadoc set to Java 5 for this question purposes).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza yes I know. Which is not the problem.

Comment: @fge which is the solution?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza implementing it... Why use FilenameFilter when implementing it is so simple?

Comment: turns out I need FileFilter anyway because I am using this with a JFileChooser and the setFilter method requires a FileFilter object as the arg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FileFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileFilter.html) is this class' parent, and implementing it for your need seems pretty trivial:

```
public final class ByExtensionFileFilter
    extends FileFilter
{
    private final String description;
    private final Set<String> extensions = new HashSet<String>();

    public ByExtensionFileFilter(final String description,
        final String first, final String... other)
    {
        this.description = description;

        extensions.add('.' + first);
        for (final String s: other)
            extensions.add('.' + s);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean accept(final File f)
    {
        final String name = f.getName();
        for (final String extension: extensions)
            if(name.endsWith(extension))
                return true;

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public String getDescription()
    {
        return description;
    }
}
```

Can be fixed with, for instance, handling names such as `.jpg` etc.

Comment: thank you. wasn't aware of filefilter. this will work for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Combination of [FilenameFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/FilenameFilter.html) and [endsWith()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith%28java.lang.String%29) method.

```
new File(".").list(new FilenameFilter(){
  public void boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
     return name.endsWith(".png");
  }
});
```

This can do pretty much the same as the `FileNameExtensionFilter`.